# Mapping (omap) to erase inside any of (), {}, [], <> or their embeddings

Tags: key-bindings

I want to map an operator-pending key combination to erase contents of any embedded combination of `(text)`, `[more text]`, `<other text>` or `{misc text}` by placing my cursor inside and issuing the `c+<mapped_key>` o `d+<mapped_key>` operator-pending mode cmds in buffer.

Until now I have always used (in `~/.vimrc`)

```
onoremap p i(
```

But that only concerns `()` and their embeddings, such that if I place my cursor on "more" inside `(text [more te <001  >xt] misc text)`, issuing `dp` will not only delete "more te <001  >xt", which is what I would like, but (as expected) everything between ( and ).  Having:

```
onoremap p( i(
onoremap p[ i[
onoremap p{ i{
onoremap p< i<
```

is not practical. I would like one mapping, NOT four different ones.

**Is there a way to `onoremap p <RHS>` to ANY occurence of (), [], <> or {} and their embeddings ?**

***EDIT:***
Please test with something such as the following line of plain text:

```
dd xsd  sdl(sddi{dss[ asd]aa }e9<888>n 0:)"wdwww
```

Comment: https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup/ has `di%` for this.  there are a few other plugins which have something similar

Comment: @Mass: Thanks ! Just read the `README.rd`.  Unless I need new glasses, deleting inside cursor-position defined brackets is not mentioned anywhere. The `vim-matchup` plugin looks great, but it's also **way** bigger than what I'd like in my vim-runtime.

Comment: @Cbhihe My solution would always select the brackets *after* the cursor. I would have edited it to first look to see if it can select the surrounding brackets, but that would be really really complicated. I'll undelete it if I can come up with a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**warning**

!!!! Dangerous cmd when used with cursor outside visible set of bracketing characters (), <>, [] or {}, because it will happily wrap around end-of-lines and greedily execute on the nearest set of unrelated opening and closing orphan bracketing symbols.

**implemention**

It's a bit complicated, read comment as explanation.

```
" objs  : any valid text object without i or a, eg: '{[(<'
" ai    : 'a' or 'i'
" force : start visual mode even if no valid text object found
"
" visually select minimal textobject
function! SelectMinTextObject(objs, ai, force)
  " init data
  let [minObj, minObjStart, minObjEnd] = ['', [], []]

  " split objs into list, loop it
  for obj in split(a:objs, '\zs')

    " get textobject range, continue if it's blank
    let [startPos, endPos] = GetTextObjectPos(a:ai . obj)
    if startPos == [] | continue | endif

    " updat data if it's empty or current text object is smaller
    if minObj ==# '' || minObjStart[1] < startPos[1] ||
          \ minObjStart[1] == startPos[1] && minObjStart[2] < startPos[2]
      let [minObj, minObjStart, minObjEnd] = [obj, startPos, endPos]
    endif

  endfor

  " return if no valid obj found
  if minObj ==# ''
    if a:force
      normal! v
    endif
    return 0
  endif

  " visually select textobject.
  execute 'normal! v'. a:ai . minObj

  return 1
endfunction

" get text object range as [startPos, endPos], pos format is the same as
" getpos(), except it returns [[],[]] if text object is blank
function! GetTextObjectPos(obj)
  try
    " record cursor, @a, '[, ']
    let [ cursorPos, regText, regType, yankPos0, yankPos1 ] =
          \ [ getcurpos(), getreg('"'), getregtype('"'),
          \   getpos("'["), getpos("']")]
    " clear register. it's necessary because "ay.. won't fill a if .. is blank
    let @a = ''
    " copy text object into @a if it's not blank
    exec 'normal! "ay' . a:obj
    " return blank if nothing copied, otherwise return start and end of copied
    " area
    return @a ==# '' ? [[],[]] : [getpos("'["), getpos("']")]
  finally
    " restore cursor, @a, '[, ']
    call setpos('.', cursorPos) | call setreg('a', regText, regType)
    call setpos("'[", yankPos0) | call setpos("']", yankPos1)
  endtry
endfunction

" you can't implement omap with vmap, because miminal v area is 1 character,
" miminal o area is 0 character
vnoremap ip <esc>:call SelectMinTextObject('({[<', 'i', 1)<cr>
vnoremap ap <esc>:call SelectMinTextObject('({[<', 'a', 1)<cr>
onoremap ip :call SelectMinTextObject('({[<', 'i', 0)<cr>
onoremap ap :call SelectMinTextObject('({[<', 'a', 0)<cr>

" dd xsd  sdl(sddi{dss[ asd]aa }e9<888>n 0:)"wdwww
```

**known issue**

`vip` will discard whatever you visually selected before. It's inconsistent with `viw`.

Comment: +1: This is grand. Thanks much, really. It is especially nice to have implemented the "a" and "i" versions of the same functionality. Allow me two comments:  (i) the line `if startPos == [] | continue | endif` did not work for me in vim 8.1. I just unfolded the if block on 3 separate lines. (ii) !!!!  Dangerous cmd when used with cursor outside visible set of bracketing characters (), <>, [] or {}, because it will happily wrap around end-of-lines and greedily execute on the nearest set of unrelated opening and closing orphan bracketing symbols. Add warning at the top of yr excellent answer ?

Comment: I tried vim8, tag v8.1.1142, coundn't recreate (i).

Comment: I am on 8.1.1073 as per Arch linux latest `extra` repo update. Stranger things happen. ;-P